# How to add URLs to the bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to add any URL of CurrentTabs here in this "popup.js" to bookmarks.

```
function GetUrls()
{
var CurrentTabs = new Array();
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        CurrentTabs[i] = tabs[i];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < CurrentTabs.length; i++) 
    {
document.write("<b>" + CurrentTabs[i].title+"</b>"+"<br/><a href='" + CurrentTabs[i].url + "' target='_blank'>" + CurrentTabs[i].url + "</a><br/><br/>");
   }
});
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", GetUrls());

document.getElementById("addBookmark").addEventListener('click',addGoogleBookmark);
function addGoogleBookmark()
{
    chrome.bookmarks.create({title:"Extension bookmarks",parentId:?????,url:"http://www.google.com"});
    alert("Added to bookmarks");
}
```

The problem here in the function addGoogleBookmark() what is the parentId?
Any idea?

And this is popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Links Collector</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="addBookmark" type="button" value="Add a Google bookmark"></input>
<style>
body {
width:500px;
height: 300px;
}
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the official documentation:

> **parentId ( optional string )**
>
> The id of the parent folder. Omitted for the root node.

As the parameter is optional for the `chrome.bookmarks.create` function, you can omit it for a default usage. In this case, the bookmark will go in the *Other Bookmarks* folder.

For more advanced usage, take a look at the [chrome.bookmarks Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html)

Comment: when i write any string,Error appear not defined.

Comment: Optional means that you can completely get rid of the parameter like this `chrome.bookmarks.create({title: "Extension bookmarks", url: "http://www.google.com"})`.